# Is there a way to make moneybookers status url work with localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I am trying to integrate moneybookers payment option with a site I am working on. Everything works except the status url which is something like: **https://localhost/mysite/checkpayment.php**. Can this really work or does moneybookers only accept live urls? I am working with php.

Answer (score 4):

I don't actually have any experience with MoneyBookers, but I'm assuming that the MoneyBookers server calls that URL to verify the payment on your end. Because MB will have to connect to that server, you cannot use localhost, since MB wouldn't know who to talk to.

Comment: I was thinking it would work like Paypal does with localhost.

Comment: PayPal doesn't use a callback, just a redirection URL. MB apparently has an actual callback.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try on a public facing server or forward your traffic through your fw if you're online?